# Objective C Theos UIView not working

Tags: theos

Well i can't get this too work. My goal is too add a UIButton into Minecraft Pocket Edition. I think the problem is easy or obvious, so please don't get destracted by the small wall of code.

Thanks soo much,
Kivifreak

```
#import <substrate.h>

 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface Tpschanger

UIButton *myButton;

UIView *myView;

-(void) TPSButton;

@end

%hook minecraftpeViewController

-(void)viewDidLoad {

myView=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,480)];

myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];

myButton.frame = CGRectMake(20, 20, 200, 44);

[myButton setTitle:@"TPS" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(TPSButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlStateNormal];

[self.myView addSubview:myButton];  

> I get an error at the previous line: request for member ‘myView’ in ‘self’, which is of non-class type ‘minecraftpeViewController*’

%orig;

}

%new
-(void) TPSButton {

}

%end
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be `[self.view addSubview:myButton];` IMO you don't need myView.